# How to set the height properties of element correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the height of my div with the following code

```
var heightMainDiv = window.innerHeight - 50;
var myDiv = $("#main_content")[0];
myDiv.clientHeight = heightMainDiv;
myDiv.scrollHeight = heightMainDiv;
```

but the values of clientHeight and scrollHeight won't change.
Means clientHeight = 50 stays 50 and won't change to f.e. 250.

Whats the problem here?

Cheers

Comment: Both the `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` properties are readonly. They are calculated by the browser and you cannot change them. Why are you trying to?

Comment: the div has to be 50px less big than the whole site / iframe

Comment: Additional, you also made a general mistake. The values for width and height needs a unit like "px". So you always have to concat it to the properties.

Comment: so set the height? `$("#main_content").height(1234)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clientHeight is not a jQuery property and scrollHeight is a read-only property that means you cannot change it.
You better use jQuery's height method:

```
myDiv.height(heightMainDiv)
```

Comment: I tried that at first but got a exception. However, now it works, thx.